# How to decide whether to retain or assign or copy variable while defining the property for the variable?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties

I'd like to know when to use `copy`, `retain` or `assign` when declaring a property.

Also, why is `nonatomic` used when declaring a property?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would I ever want to use any @property attributes other than "retain" and "nonatomic" for UI variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337835/would-i-ever-want-to-use-any-property-attributes-other-than-retain-and-nonato)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)? The answers are all in there.

This may sound like a flippant response; but the answers are in the docs. The answers you get here will just be a summary of the documentation, and you will lose the pleasure of learning about memory management for yourself, and you will get vital practice in reading Apple Documentation which will help you as your learning progresses.